# JavaScript libraries like Upshot which could be used in production

Tags: javascript, breeze

I was very impresped by Steven Sanderson presentation of Upshot, but sadly I don't think it's ready for production purposes.

What are other libraries which serves similar purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the product manager for BreezeJS and can say definitively that we Breeze is ready for production.  People are building production apps with Breeze today. The primary API is stable, the defect count is low, the documentation and support are in place. As with every library in every technology, there are capabilities on the boundary that are either incomplete or in flux. We clearly mark these as beta. Otherwise ... you're good to go.  
Of course everyone is entitled to render an opinion about readiness for production or suitability for a purpose and I respect those opinions. Just wanted to be clear about our position on this subject.

Answer (score 1):

Usually `Breeze js` is mentioned along with upshot - we have used upshot extensively, but it's not yet ready for production use.